# script/stylesheet links in index.html file served from wwwroot return 404

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am retrieving an index.html file within an action with that route:

```
/services/parts/{number}
```

from **wwwroot** folder

```
    ...
    return ContentResult(html, "text/html");
```

In the wwwroot folder I have this structure:

```
wwwroot
|
---services
   |
   ---parts
      |
      ---1
         |
         ---index.html
      |
      ---2
         |
         ---index.html

// and so on 3,4, ...
```

As I said before, retrieving the index.file and returning it is no problem, but all links/scripts in the index.html file embedded can not be loaded so I get a 404 for those links.

Then I checked why a 404 for each link:

Requested url:    URL:http://localhost:60000/services/parts/2/~/styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css

The stylesheet link in the index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Changing the stylesheet link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Result in that requested url, no big change...

```
Requested url:    URL:http://localhost:60000/services/parts/2/styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css
```

Why does the asp.net core framework try to download the bootstrap.min.css from the route services/parts/2 and not from the styles/vendor folder being subfolders under the wwwroot folder?

How do I fix that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `~` is not actually supported by browsers as part of a URL. It's a filesystem carryover that ASP.NET will replace with the document root portion of the URL. However, that only happens if ASP.NET processes the HTML, which means it has to be an ASPX, CSHTML, etc. If you just dump some HTML to the response, then that doesn't occur, and the `~` remains, resulting in a 404.

In the second attempt, you're using relative URLs. When you have a URL like `styles/vendor...`, it will be affixed to the end of the URL in the navigation bar, hence the `/service/parts/2/styles/vendor...`.

If you want to specify a path from the document root, you need to prefix your URL with `/`. In other words, `/styles/vendor`.

Comment: Awesome! Happy new year :-)

Comment: odd... it stopped working without any changes... the path for all css files is correct for the url http://localhost:56071/styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css I get a 404. But the file is put in the wwwroot in exactly that path.